# I have already installed the pip ,but it can't installed the third module

Tags: python

It shows that I have installed successfully the pip. And I want to install the PIL module, but it doesn't work. I don't know what to do next. I just write the code 'pip install PIL' in cmd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn28Z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6a7t.png)

Comment: Please post all your relevant code and error message(s) _verbatim_ in your question.

Comment: You can copy the error traceback as text and paste it as text in the question. Do it now. And what is your question? It's not clear, Improve it and make it specific.

Answer (score 0):

linux：

echo $LANG

to see coding

export $LANG="you need coding"